# Nginx timing out long query after 60 seconds

Tags: nginx

I have two tomcat instances running and nginx on the front end. Some of the queries that are executed from the webapp take longer than 60 seconds (legacy application) on the db side to execute. When this happens, exactly at 60 seconds nginx will end the session on the current machine (round robin load balancing) and then send the user to the other machine. How can I prevent this from happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding the proxy_read_timeout parameter.